# What is an Expectation Maximisation Algorithm for Markov chains?

Tags: markov-process, expectation-maximization

I'm looking for an algorithm for Expectation Maximisation of a Markov chain.
I am aware of the Baum-Welch algorithm for Hidden Markov Models, but I can't find an algorithm for Markov Models that are not hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expectation maximization algorithm is not needed to fit a fully observed Markov chain because there are no hidden variables to infer. The likelihood function depends only on the observed sequence(s) of states, and the maximum likelihood parameters (i.e. state transition probabilities and initial state distribution) can easily be calculated in closed form.

For example, the probability of transitioning from state $A$ to state $B$ is simply the number of observed $A \to B$ transitions, divided by the total number of observed transitions out of state $A$. The probability that the chain starts in state $A$ is simply the number of times we've seen $A$ as the first state, divided by the total number of sequences we've observed.